# Using angular js model inside Url.Action

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am using `PagedList.MVC` for pagination.I want to use AngularJs model with `PagedList`.
I have two searching textboxes:

```
@Html.TextBox("nameSearch", null, new { @placeholder = "Search By Name",@ng_model="name" })
@Html.TextBox("codeSearch", null, new { @placeholder = "Search By Code", @ng_code = "code" })
```

I want to use model binding in the following way:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, nameSearch = "{{name}}", codeSearch="{{code}}" }))
```

Is there any proper way to do this.